# flutter print pos image error Invalid value: Not in inclusive range 0..64377: 64522 #0

Tags: ios, flutter, printing, point-of-sale

on print image raster getting an error

E/flutter (29670): [ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(177)] Unhandled Exception: RangeError (index): Invalid value: Not in inclusive range 0..152976: 152977
E/flutter (29670): #0      List.[] (dart:core-patch/growable_array.dart:177:60)
E/flutter (29670): #1      Ticket._packBitsIntoBytes (package:esc_pos_utils/src/ticket.dart:566:16)
E/flutter (29670): #2      Ticket._toRasterFormat (package:esc_pos_utils/src/ticket.dart:675:12)
E/flutter (29670): #3      Ticket.imageRaster (package:esc_pos_utils/src/ticket.dart:694:38)
E/flutter (29670): #4      _PrinterEntryState.testTicket (package:project/printerEntry.dart:556:15)
E/flutter (29670): <asynchronous suspension>
E/flutter (29670): #5      _PrinterEntryState.testPrint (package:project/printerEntry.dart:503:24)
E/flutter (29670): <asynchronous suspension>
E/flutter (29670):